# Load multiple config Files

Tags: scala, typesafe-config

product1.conf

```
data {

 key1 {
        some-field = "some-value"
        product1 {
                  path = ${some-path}
                 }
      }
     }
```

product2.conf

```
data {

 key1 {
        some-field = "some-value"
        product2 {
                  path = ${some-path}
                 }
      }
     }
```

Desired Conf that needs to be Loaded -

```
data {

 key1 {
        some-field = "some-value"
        product1 {
                  path = ${some-path}
                 }
        product2 {
                  path = ${some-path}
                 }
      }
     }
```

In the example shown above, I have multiple conf files and all of them are required to be loaded. Previously I have tried having one single conf file instead of multiple and with the above-desired structure did help me load the configurations using -

```
val config = ConfigFactory.load(ConfigFactory.parseFile(new File(<path>)).resolve())
args.withFallback(config)
```

.

I would need help to load multiple config files. Thanks in Advance

Comment: I think `withFallback` method would help. `val c1 = ConfigFactory.load("URI"); val c2 = ConfigFactory.load("SOME-URI"); val c = c1.withFallback(c2)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the conf files are statically knowable, you can have an `application.conf` like this

```
include "product1"
include "product2"
```

which will effectively merge the two configurations.

Comment: Which would not apply in this example: the only colliding key is `data.key1.some-field`, where both of your confs happen to have the same value so it doesn't matter which one wins.

Comment: `data.key1` and `data` don't constitute keys, just a partial path.  Since the constituent configs at those paths are all objects, they are merged.